# Connect to GCP SQL using the .json credentials file

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have a PostgreSQL DB at GCP. Right now I can login using a username, password e.g

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"
    "DATABASE=test;"
    "UID=user;"
    "PWD=a_very_strong_password;"
    "SERVER=34.76.yy.xxxx;"
    "PORT=5432;"
    )


with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as con:
    print(pd.read_sql("SELECT * from entries",con=con))
```

Is there a way to use the .json credentialsfile which is downloaded when I created my IAM user, instead of "hard typing" the credentials like above? I recon I can use the file to connect to a GCP storage, where I then can save my credentials for the DB thus I can write a script which loads the username,password etc. from the storage, but I feel it is a kinda "clunky" workaround.

From the guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authentication) it seems like you can create IAM roles for such, but you only grants access for an hour at a time, and you need to create a token-pair each time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, you can connect to a Cloud SQL instance using SA keys (`json` file) but only with PostgreSQL but you need to refresh the token every hour.

Long answer: The purpouse of the `json` is more intended to make operations in the instance at resource level or when using the Cloud SQL proxy.

For example when you use the Cloud SQL proxy with a service account you make a "magical bridge" to the instance but at the end you need to [authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy#linux-64-bit) the way you're doing right now but using as `SERVER = 127.0.0.1`. This is the recommended method in most cases.

As well you've mentioned that using IAM authentication can work, this approach works for 1 hour since you depend on [token refresh](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#logging-in-as-a-user). If you're okay with this, just keep in mind you need to be refreshing the token.

Another approach I can think of for now is to use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager). The steps can be as follows:

1. Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and a [key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) for that.
2. Create a [secret](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets) which contains your password.
3. Grant access to this particular secret to the SA created in step 1:

   1. Go to [Secret Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager).
   2. Select the secret and click on **Show info panel**
   3. Click on **Add member** and type or paste the email of the SA
   4. Grant `Secret Manager Secret Accessor`
   5. Click on Save
4. Now in your code you can get the secret content (which is the password) with maybe this sample code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from google.cloud import secretmanager
from google.oauth2 import service_account


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/path/to/key.json')
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"
response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})

secret_password = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

conn_str = (
    "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"
    "DATABASE=test;"
    "UID=user;"
    "PWD=" + secret_password + ";"
    "SERVER=34.76.yy.xxxx;"
    "PORT=5432;"
    )


with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as con:
    print(pd.read_sql("SELECT * from entries",con=con))
```

BTW, you can install the lib using `pip install google-cloud-secret-manager`.

Finally, you can also use this approach to keep the instance IP, user, DB name, etc. creating more secrets if you prefer